# IDEA + Maven + SonarQube - несколько вопросов

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Буквально 3й день как начал осваивать связку IDEA + Maven + SonarCube.
Отсюда есть несколько вопросов. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

1. Как в IDEA (точнее во вкладку Maven Project) добавить sonar:sonar с нужными параметрами? Параметры - для подключения к сонару удалённой машины (локалка). Человек, который развернул у себя сонар, вообще NetBeans использует, про идею ни чего не знает, а осваивать надо. Сейчас делаю Execute Maven Goal:

   sonar:sonar -Psonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.54.233:9000 -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.54.233/sonar
2. Есть модуль в проекте, который (модуль) залит из GIT. На сонаре этот модуль уже есть (в виде проекта). При попытке подключения сонар выдает ошибку:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project new_elk: The project 'com.xxx.xxx.lk:lk_protocol' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project 'com.xxx:new_elk'. If you really want to stop directly analysing project 'com.xxx.xxx.lk:lk_protocol', please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project 'com.xxx:new_elk'. -> [Help 1]

Что можно сделать, чтобы исправить это, не удаляя проект из сонара? Оговорюсь, что этот проект (lk_protokol) используется у меня в виде модуля к основному проекту, и делать его отдельным проектом нельзя.

Буду очень благодарен за любые ответы!

Comment: Так. На второй вопрос сам ответил - достаточно в рабочей директории Execute Maven Goal указать путь к модулю, а не к проекту.

Comment: Так же нашел как сделать запуск сонара проще: (sonar:sonar -Psonar) - достаточно открыть в мавене settings.xml, и создать там профиль sonar, у которого в properties будут перечислены настройки сонара, они есть в интернетах. Позже добавлю в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продолжая любимую традицию "Сам спросил - сам ответь", отвечаю.

Чтобы не мучать Execute Maven Goal, достаточно в pom.xml (Для нужного модуля/проекта! Это важно!) указать плагин сонара и обновить мавен:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
```

После этого появится такая опция:

[image: sonar:sonar]

Достаточно просто запустить её. Если сонар развернут на удалённой машине, нужно отредактировать settings.xml у мавена:

[image: settings.xml]

И добавить туда профиль конфигурации удалённой машины и базы:

```
<profile>
  <id>sonar</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>

  <properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://192.168.54.233:9000</sonar.host.url>
    <!-- sonar:sonar -Psonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.54.233:9000 -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.54.233/sonar -->
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.54.233/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <!--<sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>-->
    <!--<sonar.jdbc.password></sonar.jdbc.password>-->
  </properties>

  <!-- Указать репозитории и плагины как у основного профиля, если надо. -->

</profile>
```

Ну, и второй вопрос разрешился сам собой - мы запускаем сонар от имени нужного модуля или проекта, а не от несущего проекта. Если же надо сделать именно Execute Maven Goal - то достаточно в верхнем поле этого окна указать путь до модуля, а не для проекта по-умолчанию.

Надеюсь, это вам поможет. Классные инструменты, очень рекомендую!